# Location Services resets after each reboot

Tags: macos, settings, privacy

Since some time back, **Location Services** are always reset after I reboot the computer. The service disables and the list of applications under **Security & Privacy** > **Location Services** goes empty. And the **LocationServicesEnabled** value goes missing from **NVRAM**. The service works fine while activated, though.

I noticed that files were not written to **/var/db/locationd** correctly. So I deleted /var/db/locationd and re-installed macOS via Recovery Mode (no wipe, just install). Which has re-created the locationd folder, but it contains only the **Library** foler. No **clients.plist**. The **com.apple.locationd.xxxx** files under **/var/db/locationd/Library/Preferences/ByHost** are aslo missing. I've tried to turn LS off/on and allow specific applications, but the files are still missing.

Any idea how I can restore Location Services functionality? I thought a re-install would restore everything...

Running macOS 11.0.1 beta 2.

I have another volume with another OS installation (also 11.0.1 beta 2) where LS works fine.

Comment: It's a beta. Report it to Apple.

Comment: Yes I know it's a beta. My question is if anyone know how to restore Location Services. Beta or not.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I have the same problem in production Monterey.